# Multipeer Video

Tags: javascript, websocket, webrtc

This question has been asked a few times before but I have been unable to make any solution work. I am creating a multi-peer video chat. However, whenever a peer tries to connect, I get this error:

> DOMException: Failed to execute 'setRemoteDescription' on 'RTCPeerConnection': Failed to set remote answer sdp: Called in wrong state: kStable

The odd thing is, if the user reloads the page, I don't get that error and the video displays. Both clients need to do the reload. I guess the browser has cached *something* and re-uses it on the 2nd attempt.

```
// When a remote user joins, an object of this class is created.
// Its job is to create am RTCPeerConnection between the local user
// and the remote user.
class VideoChat
{
    constructor(name, remoteView)
    {
        this.remoteName = name;   // ID of remote peer used by signal server
        this.remoteView = remoteView;  // html video object to display remote video

        var configuration = {"iceServers": [
            {urls: "stun:stun.l.google.com:19302"}
            {urls: "turn:numb.viagenie.ca", username: "xxx", credential: "xxx"}
        ]};

        this.pc = new RTCPeerConnection(configuration);

        // 'onicecandidate' notifies us whenever an ICE agent needs to deliver a
        // message to the other peer through the signaling server
        this.pc.onicecandidate = event => {
            if (event.candidate) {
                ChatRoom.relay("signal", this.remoteName, event.candidate);
                console.log(`onicecadidate (${this.remoteName}): ${event.candidate}`);
            }
        };

        // let the 'negotiationneeded' event create the offer
        this.pc.onnegotiationneeded = async () => {
            try {
                await this.pc.setLocalDescription();
                ChatRoom.relay("signal", this.remoteName, {desc: this.pc.localDescription})
            } catch (err) {
                console.error(err);
            }
        }

        // When a remote stream arrives display it in the #remoteView element
        this.pc.ontrack = (track, streams) => {
            log("adding remote TRACK to video element");
            // don't set srcObject again if it is already set.
            if (this.remoteView.srcObject) return;
            this.remoteView.srcObject = event.streams[0];
        };
    }

    // This is called by main program when a remote user has signed on
    // This initiates everything....
    // localVideo is html video element connected to local camera
    // stream is the main (local) user's mediaStream
    async start(localVideo, stream) {
        try {
            for (const track of stream.getTracks()) {
                this.pc.addTrack(track, stream);
            }
            localVideo.srcObject = stream;
        } catch (err) {
            console.error(err);
        }
    }

    // A message from the signal server
    async onmessage(message) {
        try {
            if (message.desc) {
                await this.pc.setRemoteDescription(message.desc);
                if (message.desc.type == "offer") {
                    await this.pc.setLocalDescription();
                    ChatRoom.relay("signal", this.remoteName, {desc: this.pc.localDescription});
                }
            }
            else if (message.candidate) {
                await this.pc.addIceCandidate(message);
            }
        } catch (err) {
            console.error(err);
        }
    }
}
```

Note the function: `ChatRoom.relay("signal", this.remoteName, something)` sends a message to signal server that gets relayed only to the remote peer with id `this.remoteName`.

Also, I am using my own signal server I created in Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set the remote description of different peers on the same peerconnection that isn't going to work. As the name "peerconnection" implied, it is specific to a peer.

Calling `this.pc.setLocalDescription()` without creating an offer may be supported in some browsers but tread carefully. Also you're never creating an answer and only signaling the local description. Nor are you doing anything with answers.

https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/peerconnection/multiple/ is a canonical example of how to do things right.

Comment: Adding `createOffer` and `createAnswer` seems to have worked. [WebRTC stuck in connecting state](//stackoverflow.com/a/62031207)